# Rsnapshot automatic backups with link_desk and sync_first

Tags: rsync, rsnapshot

My .conf file:

```
link_desk 1
sync_first 1
```

I'm using cron to do interval backups.

```
0  *  * * *     rsnapshot sync
10 *  * * *     rsnapshot hourly
30 3  * * *     rsnapshot daily
0  3  * * 1     rsnapshot weekly
30 2  1 * *     rsnapshot monthly
```

It's confusing me and i do not know if its right. **Maybe I should do sync before every cronjob or just before smallest interval?**

In the future i want run another backup with rsnapshot with seperate config file (for windwos machine).For example:

```
0  *  * * *     rsnapshot -c windows.conf sync
10 *  * * *     rsnapshot -c windows.conf hourly
30 3  * * *     rsnapshot -c windows.conf daily
0  3  * * 1     rsnapshot -c windows.conf weekly
30 2  1 * *     rsnapshot -c windows.conf monthly
```

.pid files I can separate in config file. **Would I still have incompatibility  issues with parallel running two rsnapshot process?**

**And the last question** how could I organize cronjobs? what if my sync process takes longer than coming backup command? Is it possible to run rsnapshot hourly just after rsnapshot sync?

Answer (score 3):

rsnapshot ran with `sync_first` enabled is designed for you to run one `sync` command then one or more of the interval commands as is time appropriate. Running `sync` before every cron job defeats the use of `sync_first`. You should run `sync` just before your smallest interval.

As far as organizing your cronjob, the only ordering that is critical is between the `sync` and `hourly`. `daily` will just use the oldest `hourly` available for its newest `daily.0`, `weekly` the oldest `daily` etc. `hourly` though, expects a `.sync` directory from which to create its new `hourly.0`. If `daily` runs before `hourly` it will take the 1:00 AM rather than the 2:00 AM hourly backup which gives you nearly, but not exactly, the same backup coverage. You'll need to decide if that's critical for your situation.

When faced with your question I created a small script file that ran `rsnapshot sync` followed by `rsnapshot hourly` and scheduled that in cron.

I have no experience running snapshots in parallel. As long as you are backing up to different directories I predict no issues beyond CPU and network usage. It will be like starting a second `rsync` command by hand before a previous one completes.

Comment: Can you help me understand why you stated "Running 'sync' before every cron job defeats the use of 'sync_first'. You should run 'sync' just before your smallest interval." @ItsJustBits why is that?  Thanks

Comment: The answer is wrong. You have to call 'rsnapshot sync' before running rsnapshot hourly, daily and so on. [rsnapshot manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsnapshot)  

When sync_first is enabled, rsnapshot must first be called with the sync argument, followed by the other usual cron entries. The sync should happen as the lowest, most 
frequent backup level, and right before.